# How can i get the records greater then or equal to persons in sql or laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel

i have a condition where user have to select number of person in input and on basis of that i have to fetch the records,

[image]
if user select route_id 5 and enter number of person 2 then row with id 1 only shows up similarly if user enter number of person9 then row with id of 3 shows up because 9 is less the 10..cool

```
SELECT * FROM `transfer_pricings` WHERE route_id = 5 AND persons >= 11 GROUP BY route_id
```

i'm using this query and this working fine but when data changes to this in table (last two row 3,4)

[image]

And try to run this query

```
SELECT * FROM `transfer_pricings` WHERE route_id = 5 AND persons >= 9 GROUP BY route_id
```

but the row i get is 3 not 4 of second table

**how can i do this in perfect way?**

Comment: if you run your second query get only two records because of in `person` column  two record greater then `9`.

Comment: yes i know the reason but how can i make it perfect and how can i convert my first query  in laravel eloquent?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: @jarlh You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

For your laravel query:

```
DB::table('transfer_pricings')      
    ->WHERE('route_id', '5')
    ->WHERE('persons', '>=', '9')
    ->groupBy('persons')
    ->get();
```